# How to force a subdomain as a default domain but keep other subdomains working?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have a WordPress site installed at `http://www.example.com` and another testing WordPress site at `http://test.example.com`. I've successfully made `http://www.example.com` redirect to `http://beta.example.com` with this .htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^beta\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://beta.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, when trying to go to `http://test.example.com` it forces it to `http://beta.example.com/test/` with a 404 error. Is there a way to have this beta redirect but still keep my WordPress site at `http://test.example.com` working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly and you want test.example.com to still go to test.example.com. You can add another condition and both conditions will have to be met for the rule to be followed. It would look like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^beta\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://beta.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now neither `beta` nor `test` subdomains will redirect, but ALL others will.

If you only want www.example.com or example.com to go to the `beta` subdomain you could use

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://beta.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

There is a nifty tool for checking mod rewrite rules at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Alternatively, if you have access to your servers zone file you could set up CNAME records for all domains that you want to point to the `beta` subdomain and no redirect would occur so that if a user goes to www.example.com the URL remains the same when they are in fact on the beta site.

Comment: Adding another condition makes complete sense! Thanks for your help!